# In frontmatter after toc suddenly pagenumbering gets arabic

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, front-matter, roman

I can't find why the page-numbering after a chapter (or even toc) in front-matter switches to arabic. I would appreciate any helps and hints to fix this.

Here is my (edited) code:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,                                
DIV=calc,                           
parskip=half,version=first,             
%headsepline,                   
%numbers=noenddot
]{scrbook}


\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[includehead=false, includefoot=false, paperheight=240mm, paperwidth=170mm, 
twoside=true, left=25mm, right=20mm, 
top=35mm, 
bottom=20mm]{geometry}



\usepackage[format=plain, font=small, font=it, labelfont=it, labelfont=small,
width=12.5cm, indention=.5cm]{caption}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek,farsi,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}



\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[authordate-trad,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}



\begin{document}


\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\centering

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{bfseries} \Large
Something\\
\end{bfseries}

\vspace*{2.5cm}

Vom Fachbereich Something\\
zur Erlangung der Würde eines\\
Doktors der Philosophie (Dr. Phil.)\\
genehmigte Dissertation\\

\vspace*{2.5cm}

vorgelegt von\\[1.3ex]
\textbf{\large Something}\\[1ex]


\vspace*{2.5cm}

\begin{tabular}{r@{\extracolsep{1em}}l} 
Hauptberichter: & Prof. Dr. Something\\
Mitberichter: & Prof. Dr. Something\\
\end{tabular}\\[1ex]
Tag der mündlichen Prüfung: xx.xx.2019

\vspace*{2cm}

Something\\
2019 
\end{titlepage}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------


\newpage\null\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Abstrakt}


\tableofcontents





\mainmatter

\chapter{Something1}

Somethings in chapter 1.

\chapter{Something2}

Somethings in chapter 2.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a _minimal_ code that people can _test_.

Comment: Hey Phirma, because we don't know whats  in e.g. `Chap1.tex` we can't help you. Does the problem persist if you take out `Chap1.tex`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I changed the code. The problem exists independent of Chap1.tex. It can be now tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue bases on the redefinition of the pagestyles by the babel option `farsi`. 
If you really want to use the outdated package `scrpage2`, you can add

```
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{scrplain}
```

But I would remove package `scrpage2` and load its successor `scrlayer-scrpage` **after** `babel`. `scrlayer-scrpage` redefines pagestyle `plain` as alias of `plain.scrheadings` and activates pagestyle `scrheadings` automatically.

Example:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
%DIV=calc,% layout settings will be overwritten by geometry
parskip=half,
version=first,% Do you really want compatilbility to version 2.9? Current version is 3.26
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
index=totoc,
%cleardoublepage=empty% empty blank pages
]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}

\usepackage[includehead=false, includefoot=false, paperheight=240mm, paperwidth=170mm, 
twoside=true, left=25mm, right=20mm, top=35mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek,farsi,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- after babel

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} not needed with an uptodate TEX distribution
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\vspace*{1cm}
{\bfseries \Large Titlepage\par}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Abstrakt}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Something1}
Somethings in chapter 1.
\chapter{Something2}
Somethings in chapter 2.
\end{document}
```

Note that I have removed the unrelated stuff. Additionally there is no need to load package `tocbibind` with a KOMA-Script class. It can be replaced by the class options `listof=totoc`, `bibliography=totoc`, `index=totoc` and by `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}`.

Result:

[image: screenshot: TOC]